Video recorded by OBS. I am unable to forward or skip through it
I recorded a Meet chat by OBS Studio (30.0.0 64bit).
I got a almost two hours long .mkv video. I may look at it by VLC (3.0.21 Vetinari).
Issue  is that I am unable to forward or skip through it.
If I try to move forward the progress bar, either it idles for a long time, or just halts.  It is not better for the .mp4  file I got by remux.
I am a OBS newbie, to record I used a couple of default settings. I did not save the .log. (I am on a Fedora 39 machine)
Sorry, I miss some basics to understand what could have been gone wrong, or if I have missed to do something. Is there a way to fix it?

Yes, I had seen, but I didn't read any good answer. Is there a way to convert to something which works?
